# Arabic encoding is not displaying preperly on some pages

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, arabic

I have a weird problem. Arabic characters are not displayed properly in one master page

[image: Wrong Arabic Display]

while it is displayed just find in another master page

[image: Correct Arabic Display]

noting that both master pages are using the same CSS file and have the same encoding

```
<html lang="ar-sa">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

In addition, everything is working fine in the development site but the issue appears when I deploy the site to the hosting server.

Any help is appreciated

**Edit:**

It is important to note that the page itself is fine in displaying the Arabic characters. ONLY the footer part is not displaying properly. It's weird because the footer is exactly the same (CSS - Layout - Characters) in both master pages!

[image: Whole page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I added the following line into web.config under system.web tag and it fixed the problem:

```
<system.web>
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check both master page and page file encoding. (not only meta tag, encoding of file). Refer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file) to find out encoding of file.